# How do I convert status(string) from http request to status_id(number) before applying business logic

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

This code is written in nestjs with typeorm
I m using DTO (Data Transfer Object)

**create-enquiry.dto.ts**

```js
export class CreateEnquiryReqDto {

  @IsNotEmpty()
  location: string
  

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(EnquiryStatusEnum)
  status: EnquiryStatusEnum

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => CreateCustomerDto)
  customer: CreateCustomerDto

}
```

this is the request object

```js
{
    "location": "Karnataka",
    "status": "NEW"
}
```

**This is enquiryStatusEnum**

```js
export enum EnquiryStatusEnum {
  NEW = 1,
  CONVERTED,
  CANCELLED
}
```

Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to dynamically get the value of an enum through the enum key, you can use:

```
EnquiryStatusEnum[status as keyof typeof EnquiryStatusEnum]
```